# ¿Formato 12H fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Tengo problemas al momento de poder el siguiente código para pasar a 12horas mi calendario
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el calendario me sale de esta manera [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguna solución?

Comment: ¿Si le quitas la coma que aparece al final de **meridiem: 'short',** mejora algo?

Comment: No, sigue igual

Comment: Pero si lo pones de otra forma, como por ejemplo, `slotLabelFormat: 'HH:MM',`, ¿te sigue pasando o solo cuando pones eso?  Quizás es la versión de fullcalendar que tienes que no soporta esos atributos, revisa cual es y por cual van ahora.